# What does "aria-disabled" do?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, class

I found that a code to disable the text in Bootsrap can stood by itself with major class (`disabled`)

```html
<a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">
  Disabled
</a>
```

But it can work without the `aria-disabled` attribute too:

```html
<a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1">
  Disabled
</a>
```

Seeing the result is the same, the text is still disabled, I am wondering what is the purpose of the `aria` attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is there so that screen readers will be able to detect the disabled button/link.

For your reference check:

- https://a11y-101.com/development/aria-disabled
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA